# Make a Panel open when i click a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

does anyone know how to make a GUI button open up a new JPanel in java? its not on google. its to show an about panel. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) is what you need.

See this for details : [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Here is a sample :

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CreateDialogFromOptionPane {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        JFrame parent = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton();

        button.setText("Click me to show dialog!");
        parent.add(button);
        parent.pack();
        parent.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Is this what you need?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Dialog");
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ive never used that. could u give an example of use?

Comment: it isnt working. im using the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs aren't supposed to be green.");` example, but the `showMessageDialog` is being highlighted as wrong, and so is `frame` because "it cant find the variable FRAME"

Comment: very good, but from Jave Desktop Aplications you have to extract this container sooooo terrible way, same way isn't possible to change jFrame's Icon, etc.... +1

Comment: that worked perfectly! thanks for the help! srry for the late response btw.

Answer (score 2):

I think that by implements [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) you can solve that

Comment: ok. do u know where i would impliment that in netbeans with the auto gen code?

Comment: because that is exactly what i want, except i want a button to do that, not a drop down menu

Comment: not possible directly, because Java Deskop Aplications is Framework based on Swing methods, I never use that because as you see, not possible lots of basic methods write directly, there are implemnted onw logics, Swing as you can see on this forum is (majorities of them) about write code by hands,

Answer (score 2):

first you would need to create an event handler for your button, then in your handler you should create your panel and make it visible. if you want more of a popup you should use like:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "This is my message");
```

that will create a warning message, you could also create your own costume dialog i would suggest reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can show panel using an undecorated JDialog

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         final JDialog bwin = new JDialog();
         bwin.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener()
         {
             @Override
             public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e)
             {
               bwin.setVisible(false);
               bwin.dispose();
             }

             @Override
             public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e)
             {
             }
         }); 

        bwin.setUndecorated(true);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("About");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        bwin.add(panel);
        bwin.pack();
        bwin.setVisible(true);
    }
```